# Built Expo Go React Native app crashes on splash screen - Incompatibility error or old app version

Tags: android, react-native, expo, sdk, eas

I installed my react native expo app on my phone that was built using

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

but after running the app, it crashes and this error notification shows up:

[image]

and it was just working fine when running on expo go development mode. Is the problem on the  SDK version of the app or is it the dependencies? The SDK version of the app is 48.0.0 and my device android 11. I have updated the expo-cli and the dependencies to the recent version.
This is my app's app.json, package.json, and eas.json

```
app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Renthive",
    "slug": "Renthive", 
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.mopheadkim.Renthive"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "05f45ca6-5fdb-418e-b456-8719e9394a37"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
package.json
{
  "name": "renthive",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "clean:android": "echo 'require(\"child_process\").execSync(\"cd android; ./gradlew clean\", {stdio: \"inherit\"})' | node ",
    "clean:ios": "echo 'require(\"child_process\").execSync(\"cd ios; xcodebuild clean\", {stdio: \"inherit\"})' | node ",
    "clean": "npm run clean:android && npm run clean:ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.14",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1300.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-sms-android": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.4.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    }, 
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

[image]

Please help. This is for my school project :(